# remove % from chart.js graph

Tags: javascript, css, graph, chart.js

I have integrated [chart.js tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/positioning.html) graph. Graph is showing some random value like 78% in the mid of the graph. I dont know from where it is coming.

Please have a look on the image. Please tell me how to remove it as I cant find it on chart.js examples and on google.

[example image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0Nv.png)

[example image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzy5P.png)

Below is my code

```
function createConfig(position) {
    var today = new Date();
    var first = formatDate(new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-6)));
    var today = new Date();
    var second = formatDate(new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-5)));
    var today = new Date();
    var third = formatDate(new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-4)));
    var today = new Date();
    var fourth = formatDate(new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-3)));
    var today = new Date();
    var fifth = formatDate(new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-2)));
    var today = new Date();
    var sixth = formatDate(new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-1)));
    var today = new Date();
    var today = formatDate(today);

    console.log(desktop_data);

    return {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, today],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Desktop',
                borderColor: '#376593',
                backgroundColor: '#376593',
                data: desktop_data,
                fill: false,
            }, {
                label: 'Mobile',
                borderColor: '#ffa200',
                backgroundColor: '#ffa200',
                data: mobile_data,
                fill: false,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true
            },
            tooltips: {
                position: position,
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
        }
    };
}

var chart;

window.onload = function() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.container_chart');

    ['average'].forEach(function(position) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('chart-container');

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        div.appendChild(canvas);
        container.appendChild(div);

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var config = createConfig(position);
        chart = new Chart(ctx, config);

    });
};
```

Comment: pls add your code in codepen or Fiddle

Comment: Better add a link to a working example instead of an image.. it's easier for us to help you if we can see how your code is working

Comment: Welcome to SO, please paste your minimal working code so that we can help, for time being search 78% in you html file i think its written some where in html

Comment: @TharinduVindula, I have added code, please check now

Comment: @AphroPfotte I think it would be better to see the example working, maybe a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue), because I don't know how are you defining `formatDate` ..also I think it would be good to see how is your html looking